# How to convert Path to 8.3 format with Inno Setup

Tags: delphi, inno-setup

I need to get 8.3 formatted path (in this case `{app}`) for registry entry.

Unfortunately this specific Delphi function does not work in Inno Setup

`function ExtractShortPathName(const S: FullFileName): string;`

Comment: Are you sure you need the 8.3 name? Sometimes people think they need this but what they actually need is to put quotes in the right places.  8.3 names are legacy DOS things that generally should not be used any more, and may not even be available on some versions of Windows. (They can be disabled by the admin.)

Comment: @Miral - yep, I'm sure. It's old app, and it looks for 8.3 path in registry. If it is not 8.3 it displays error (but works fine by the way) :) I could trace this check with decompiler, but... it's easier to give the app what it wants :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`GetShortName`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getshortname.htm) function. From the reference:

> Returns the short version of the specified long filename. If the short
>   version of the long filename is not found, the long filename is
>   returned.

Comment: FYI, both functions, the `ExtractShortPathName` in Delphi as well as the `GetShortName` in InnoSetup uses internally the same Windows API function `GetShortPathName`.